# automapper causing multiple database calls when map many-to-many relations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, automapper

Please advice. I use automapper to map the following models. The problem is circular reference  ( i am not sure how it`s called ) when mapping many-to-many. Check the code.

```
public class PostAnnotationViewModel 
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Content { get; set; }
     public ICollection<TagAnnotationViewModel> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class TagAnnotationViewModel 
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name{ get; set; }
     public ICollection<PostAnnotationViewModel> Posts { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult GetAll()
{
     var posts = this.postService.GetAll().ToList();
     var postsModel = mappingService
                .Map<IEnumerable<Post>, ICollection<PostAnnotaionViewModel>>(posts);
}
```

Code is simplified, but the idea is same. Code works, it maps correctly, in the view i can access the tags from post model as i want. The problem is the following image. [SQL Server Profiler screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wWbc.jpg) . In words, instead of making one request, it makes a multiple same requests.

Please advice good practices for solving this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: See [Queryable Extensions](http://automapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html) AutoMapper documentation topic.

Comment: your viewmodels are causing it because they constantly refer back to each other. Construct a simpler viewmodel.

Comment: Thank you. I understood how it works. What if services return IEnumerable? I do not want controllers to have access to database.

Comment: @drobb Then you'll suffer the performance. It's not an AutoMapper problem. IQueryable is crucial because it gives the query provider opportunity to optimize the final query to be executed. While with IEnumerable you are stuck with LINQ to Objects implementation.